# Assign values to answers from a questionnaire, input into a formula and calculate score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if anyone could make any suggestions to how I could write the following more concisely and reduce the number of IF statements? If possible, I would also like to simultaneously assign values to variables and calculate the score.

I will eventually have multiple rule sets and formula scores for other question sets.

```py
# q001 is multiple choice with three choices - q001_a01, q001_a02 & q001_a03 - only one selection can be made
# q002 is the first part of a two part question. It has two options = q002_a01 & q002_a02 - again, only one selection can be made
# q003 is only answered if q002_a01 is selected in q002 and also has two choices - q003_a01 & q003_a02
# q004 is a multiple choice question with 5 options - q004_a01, q004_a02, q004_a03, q004_a04 & q004_a05 - multiple selections can be made, q004_a05 answer is 'none of the above' 
# q005 is a simple Yes/No (True/False) question
# q006 is multiple choice with three choices - q006_a01, q006_a02, q006_a03 & q006_a004 - only one selection can be made
# q007 is multiple choice with three choices - q007_a01, q007_a02 & q007_a03 - only one selection can be made
# q008 requires an input of an integer from 1-5
# all questions require a response (except q003)

# dictionary containing question and answer codes for a single individuals response
data = {'q001': 'q001_a01',
        'q002': 'q002_a01',
        'q003': 'q003_a02',
        'q004': ['q004_a01', 'q004_a02', 'q004_a04'],
        'q005': False,
        'q006': 'q006_a03',
        'q007': 'q007_a01',
        'q008': 3}

# rules which define the values of the different variables
var1 = 2 if 'q001_a01' in data['q001'] else 0
var1 = 5 if 'q001_a02' in data['q001'] or 'q001_a03' in data['q001'] else var1

var2 = -2 if 'q002_a01' in data['q002'] and 'q003_a01' in data['q003'] else 0
var2 = 2 if 'q002_a01' in data['q002'] and 'q003_a02' in data['q003'] else var2

var3 = 2 if 'q004_a01' in data['q004'] else 0
var3 = var3 + 2 if 'q004_a02' in data['q004'] else var3
var3 = var3 - 1 if 'q004_a03' in data['q004'] else var3
var3 = var3 + 1 if 'q004_a04' in data['q004'] else var3
var3 = 5 if 'q004_a05' in data['q004'] else var3

var4 = 4 if True is data['q005'] else 0

var5 = 1 if 'q006_a01' in data['q006'] else 0
var5 = 2 if 'q006_a02' in data['q006'] else var5
var5 = -10 if 'q006_a03' in data['q006'] else var5
var5 = -2 if 'q006_a04' in data['q006'] else var5

var6 = 2 if 'q007_a01' in data['q007'] else 0
var6 = 1 if 'q007_a02' in data['q007'] or 'q007_a03' in data['q007'] else var6

var7 = data['q008']

# formula to calculate score from variables
score = var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + ((var5 + var6) * var7)
```

I would like to make the code as neat and fast as possible.
Also, could someone point me towards some python literature which would help me improve this myself?

Comment: Can you share the *prototype* (origin) of that formula? where did you get the idea?

Comment: The rules don't really seem to have much consistency that could be taken advantage of. I think the best you could do is construct some structure that holds the different data associated with each var, then iterate over it. That would still be difficult though as they "q" key strings aren't entirely consistent either.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I will try and construct some structure as there is only a finite number of different question types (single answer from a list, multiple selection from a list, Yes/No or True/False, input a numerical value).

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest unfortunately I cannot share the origin of that formula. However, the basic idea is that combined answers from specific sets of questions and according to the prescribed rules will be used to generate scores for different formulas which can then be used in downstream processes to help make some form of decision.

Comment: Since nothing has descriptive names it's hard to discern the underlying logic.  Is the idea that your `data` represents a sample "test" (with answers that may or may not be right), and the correct answers plus the scoring weights are encoded in the rest of the code?

Comment: Are answers expected to have a certain type (e.g. `str` vs `List` vs `bool`) based on the question, or could I (for example) pass a giant list of responses for `q002` since if I hit the right ones it'll override the negative score for all the wrong ones?  The use of `in` for most of the checks implies that a list is acceptable input, but that doesn't match the data so I'm not sure if it's intentional or a coding error.

Comment: @SamStafford I'm sorry if it is all a bit vague/unclear, there is only so much information I can divulge. The `data` represents the answers to a set of questions, there are no correct/incorrect answers but the combined answers given will be used to calculate a score which would then be used to make a decision downstream. For example another set of questions for an individual to answer.

Comment: If the only information you can divulge about what you're trying to accomplish is the code itself it's not really possible to suggest a way to write it to better accomplish your intent.  It *looks* like there might be some generalizable patterns in there for certain types of questions -- there are multiple-answer questions where the score is a weighted sum, and single-answer questions where each possible answer maps to a score, and it'd be possible to implement those patterns much more elegantly, but that implementation wouldn't be bug-for-bug compatible so with no "spec"... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SamStafford ok I can see how the question as it doesn't give enough info to really help too much. I will add more info regarding the questions to improve it.

Answer (score 4):

Since everything in this code is defined statically rather than as a function input (and your comments indicate that there is no way to vary any part of how this code functions), there is no possibility allowed within the parameters of this question for the score to ever vary.  You can therefore make this code significantly more concise and efficient by simply computing the score statically:

```
score = -15
```

This will produce the same score result as your original code with a significantly smaller footprint.

If this doesn't seem right, the question to ask yourself (and then answer for the benefit of your code reviewers) is: which constants in this code can vary, and what types/values are permissible for them?

Answer (score 1):

#### Restructuring and optimization

The initial approach is totally relies on *if-else ternary* conditions, supposedly attempting to make the code compact.
 But in this case it was overused and comes to negative effects in readability and redundant reassignment to the same variable multiple times (all those numerous `var = ... else var`)

One subtle detail that might be unnoticed at 1st glance is that all conditions for variables **`var1`**, **`var2`**, **`var3`**(partially), **`var5`** and **`var6`** are checked with *precedence* in relation to the final value assigned to a related variable.
Let's look at the sequence of conditions for **`var5`**:

```
var5 = 1 if 'q006_a01' in data['q006'] else 0
var5 = 2 if 'q006_a02' in data['q006'] else var5
var5 = -10 if 'q006_a03' in data['q006'] else var5
var5 = -2 if 'q006_a04' in data['q006'] else var5
```

if `'q006_a04' in data['q006']` is *truthy* then `var5` is just assigned with `-2` and **all** previous conditions become redundant. The same applies for other variables mentioned above. 
That means that the optimal way is to build the conditional flow in *"upstream"* manner (basing on precedence).

The intermediate optimizations include:

- all variables (except `var7`) is initialized at once:

  ```
  var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = var5 = var6 = 0
  ```
- `var2` block has a common condition `'q002_a01' in data['q002']`. *Consolidate conditional expression* technique is applied (see below)
- `4 if True is data['q005'] else 0` is simply the same as **`4 if questionnaire['q005'] else 0`**

Considering the above conception and optimizations the restructured version is below (defined as **`calc_score`** function):

```
def calc_score(questionnaire):
    # rules which define the values of the different variables
    var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = var5 = var6 = 0

    if 'q001_a02' in questionnaire['q001'] or 'q001_a03' in questionnaire['q001']:
        var1 = 5
    elif 'q001_a01' in questionnaire['q001']:
        var1 = 2

    if 'q002_a01' in questionnaire['q002']:
        if 'q003_a02' in questionnaire['q003']:
            var2 = 2
        elif 'q003_a01' in questionnaire['q003']:
            var2 = -2

    if 'q004_a05' in questionnaire['q004']:
        var3 = 5
    else:
        if 'q004_a01' in questionnaire['q004']:
            var3 = 2
        if 'q004_a02' in questionnaire['q004']:
            var3 += 2
        if 'q004_a03' in questionnaire['q004']:
            var3 -= 1
        if 'q004_a04' in questionnaire['q004']:
            var3 += 1

    var4 = 4 if questionnaire['q005'] else 0

    if 'q006_a04' in questionnaire['q006']:
        var5 = -2
    elif 'q006_a03' in questionnaire['q006']:
        var5 = -10
    elif 'q006_a02' in questionnaire['q006']:
        var5 = 2
    elif 'q006_a01' in questionnaire['q006']:
        var5 = 1

    if 'q007_a02' in questionnaire['q007'] or 'q007_a03' in questionnaire['q007']:
        var6 = 1
    elif 'q007_a01' in questionnaire['q007']:
        var6 = 2

    var7 = questionnaire['q008']

    # formula to calculate score from variables
    score = var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + ((var5 + var6) * var7)
    return score


# dictionary containing question and answer codes for an individual
data = {'q001': 'q001_a01',
        'q002': 'q002_a01',
        'q003': 'q003_a02',
        'q004': ['q004_a01', 'q004_a02', 'q004_a04'],
        'q005': False,
        'q006': 'q006_a03',
        'q007': 'q007_a01',
        'q008': 3}

print(calc_score(data))    # -15
```